# fastest way to create huge files?

Tags: ruby, file

I need to create a huge file filled with anything. I'm doing it this way but it takes so long:

```
exit 1 unless ARGV.length > 0
File.open("file-#{ARGV[0]}M.txt", 'w') do |f| 
  (ARGV[0].to_i*1048576).times {f.write(1) }
end
```

What's the best way of doing that (in platform independent way?)

Comment: What's the reason you need to create a huge file? Do the contents matter, or does it just need to be a large file full of gibberish? (If it's really performance sensitive, you might want to write it in C and link to it from Ruby).

Comment: I just need to have lots of differently sized huge files for my testing purposes. The content doesn't matter at all.

Comment: How big and how fast are we talking? I'm fooling with a concept, got about 1.5 gigs in around 20 seconds. That might be too slow for you though.

Comment: This exact program takes over 10 sec to create 50Mb file on Windows

Comment: Oh, wow, really? I'll post an answer with what I'm doing then, and you can jigger with it to adjust to your needs. Just gimme a bit...

Comment: yes, really :) `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]` and windows 7

Comment: the trivial `s = "x"*1048576; ARGV[0].to_i.times { f.write(s) }` is too slow also?

Comment: @tokland but it will first fill up RAM with gigs of "x"s won't it?

Comment: @Oleg: Not gigs, just 1Mb, which is nothing for nowadays computers. But pick the block size you want, 10K, 100K, whatever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby increase file size on the fly for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562085/ruby-increase-file-size-on-the-fly-for-testing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In *nix,** use `dd`:

```
system("dd if=/dev/zero of=" + f + " bs=1 count=0 seek=" + ARGV[0] + "M");
```

If you want some content (instead of zeros) in the file, use

```
/dev/random
```

for `if` instead of `/dev/zero`

If you want a non-sparse file, use

```
bs=#{ARGV[0]}M
```

and omit `seek`

---

**Universal method:**

```
#Create a 1M fill buffer
fills = '1'*1048576
File.open("file-#{ARGV[0]}M.txt", 'w') do |f| 
  (ARGV[0].to_i).times {f.write(fills) }
end
```

It is similar to the one you have, but it writes 1M at a time. You write 1 byte at a time which creates a lot of overhead for hard disk to search and write. Writing 1M at a time will be much faster. If you have an even faster hard drive (like 16M/s), you can try to increase 1M to 16M.

Comment: I believe this will create a sparse file on filesystems supporting it... It depends on if he wants a sparse file or a true file

Comment: @Earlz well you can use /dev/random as I edited so it will be no difference at all

Comment: You should also be able to not use the `seek` directive in dd if all zeros is OK to you. Without seek it won't be sparse... Also, /dev/random is significantly slower than /dev/zero for obvious reasons

Comment: Sure without seek or with seek, either is ok. For the original poster, I believe zeros will be enough for his purpose.

Comment: sorry guys - I'm on Windows, and I'm looking for a universal method

Comment: Removing my answer and upvoting this one, because I technically solved for the wrong problem (thought we just wanted random size files, as opposed to specified size). This is probably the method to go with.

Answer (score 3):

A pure Ruby option:

```
n = ARGV[0] or exit 1
File.open("file-#{n}M.txt", 'w') do |f| 
  contents = "x" * (1024*1024)
  n.to_i.times { f.write(contents) }
end
```